# How to free an app when clicking on the home button

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

I have a problem with one of my apps. When I open my app and just go through it. close it with my home button of the phone and reopen the app I get an `access violation at address` error. This error only appears on code where the component TMSFMXCheckGroup is used. Now I have some ideas to solve it but don't know if they are good and works.

1. Just fully close the app when the app closes via the home button so the app opens next time with a clear cache.
2. I want to empty all CheckGroups so only the checkgroups start fresh.
3. when the app closes via the home button next time you open it begins on the home page of the app.

I don't know if one of these solutions works and how I implement this in my code.

If there is another solution that's better let me know!

Thanks in advance for all the help.

I've looked at the other questions and the answers but with no result.
The solutions they had didn't work for me because my app is on ios and android so I need a solution for both.

Comment: Can you please explain better how linked answers don't work. Point 1. is covered there, you should add hardware button event handler and in that event handler you can do any action you need - close application (which does not work on iOS) but you can also do 2. empty check groups to avoid the crash. If you close the application, then next time it will automatically start from the initial screen like you want in 3.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Do you know the Hardware handler for the home button of the phone I tried it with vkHardwareBack and my code worked but know the vk needs to be the home button

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar if have this code under formkeyup procedure                                       `  if Key = vkBrowserHome then
       TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem1;`                                                                                          But it wont work when i click on the home button do you know whats wrong. This is all new for me

Comment: It seems that vkBrowserHome button is not handled by key press events on Android. Solutions require handling application lifecycle events. That should also be a solution on iOS side. You can possibly find some answers here https://blogs.embarcadero.com/mobile-app-lifecycle-events-handling-in-delphi-xe5/

Comment: IMO, it would be better to find and solve the problem that's causing the AV, rather than attempt to work around it. I don't have a single Android app on my phone that closes itself when I hit the Home button - I can always return to them any time I want, with them containing the state they were in when I hit Home. That's the way Android apps work., and your users are going to expect the same behavior from your app.

Comment: @KenWhite well there you have a good point but I tried to solve the problem it seems like the app holds a piece of code what causes the error

Comment: That's what I mean by *find and solve the problem* - locate that *piece of code what causes the error* and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To react on the home button under android you can implement a Application Event Handler and react on WillBecomeInactive or WillBecomeForeground to return to the home screen of your app.
I use this method to save my data when entering background to prevent data loss when an App is closed while in background.

The Event Handler is installed using

```
IF TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, IInterface(AppEventSvc)) THEN
    AppEventSvc.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent);
```

in your forms oncreate method.
The Event handler itself could look like the following:

```
FUNCTION Tmainform.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
BEGIN
  IF (AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.EnteredBackground) OR (AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeInactive) THEN
  BEGIN
    // do any action here; 
  END
  ELSE IF (AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground) THEN
  BEGIN
    // do any action here; 
  END;
END;
```

I would go for the WillBecomeForeground in your case.

Comment: @andreReubel Thank you for your solution I think this is the best way to execute code when the app goes to the background or foreground. Now i dont need to send it to the homepage but search a better solution for the error